# cancer model, filling matrix with loop gives error message " missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

Tags: r

i am doing a simulation for cancer patients and have a new problem in my model.
while trying to fill a matrix and always get the same error message:

"Error in if (m.Results[i, t - 1] == "o.SURV_NC") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

my aim is that column 2 will set as o.DEAD if in the previous cell there was already o.DEAD

example

```
n.i<-5
n.t<-10

m.Results <- matrix(nrow = n.i, ncol = n.t)

m.Results[1, 1] = "o.SURV_NC"  

m.Results[2, 1] = "o.SURV_NC"  

m.Results[3, 1] = "o.DEAD"

m.Results[4, 1] = "o.DEAD"  

m.Results[5, 1] = "o.DEAD"  

for (t in 2:n.t) {    
  for (i in 1:n.i) {  


    if (m.Results[i, t - 1] == "o.SURV_NC") {
      m.Results[i, t] = "o.SURV_NC"
    }
  }
}
```

interestingly the error message disappears if first fill the whole matrix with a number. however the "o.DEAD" is not put in the second column as supposed

example (no error message but wrong funciton):

```
n.i<-5
n.t<-10

m.Results <- matrix(9, nrow = n.i, ncol = n.t)

m.Results[1, 1] = "o.SURV_NC"  

m.Results[2, 1] = "o.SURV_NC"  

m.Results[3, 1] = "o.DEAD"

m.Results[4, 1] = "o.DEAD"  

m.Results[5, 1] = "o.DEAD"  

for (t in 2:n.t) {    #open loop for columns
  for (i in 1:n.i) {  #open loop for rows
    #     
    #PREVIOUSLY DEAD PATIENTS
    if (m.Results[i, t - 1] == "o.SURV_NC") {
      m.Results[i, t] = "o.SURV_NC"
    }
  }
}
```

thank you so much for any advice

Comment: you could do `m.Results <- matrix('', nrow = n.i, ncol = n.t)` instead

Comment: well the 9 is not the problem, actually i want that cell in the second column is set as o.DEAD if the cell in the first column was already o.DEAD

Comment: 9 actually is the problem. It's the fact that in your example, you start with a matrix of `NA`s, and comparing `NA` to another value will always yield `NA`. The reason using 9 or `''` works is that you are now comparing 9 or `''` to another value (namely `"o.SURV_NC"`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't give an alternative for when `m.Results[i, t - 1] == "o.SURV_NC"`is `FALSE`, so you end up comparing `"o.SURV_NC"` to `NA`, which is always `NA` (i.e., not `TRUE` or `FALSE`), and `if` requires `TRUE` or `FALSE`. There are a few ways to get around this.

You can use `isTRUE()`, so your `if` statement will read

```
if (isTRUE(m.Results[i, t - 1] == "o.SURV_NC"))
```

This will leave the `NA`s as they are in your matrix. Or, you can fill in the matrix values with something else when the previous column is not `"o.SURV_NC"`:

```
if (m.Results[i, t - 1] == "o.SURV_NC") {
  m.Results[i, t] = "o.SURV_NC"
}
else m.Results[i, t] = "o.DEAD"
```